# I$ \frac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{b^{2} + c^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{c^{2} + a^{2} + 1} \ge 1 \implies ab + ac + bc \le 3$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $a,b,c >0$ and $$ \frac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{b^{2} + c^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{c^{2} + a^{2} + 1} \ge 1 $$
prove that $ab + ac + bc \le 3$

---

**Attempt:**

We can show that $\frac{1}{3} \le \frac{1}{ab+bc+ac}$. Or we can show that: $a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} \le 3$ (Since by $AM-GM$, $ab + ac + bc \le a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}$).

Notice that 
$$ \frac{1}{a^{2} + b^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{b^{2} + c^{2} + 1} + \frac{1}{c^{2} + a^{2} + 1} \ge 1 $$

implies

$$ 2 \ge \frac{a^{2} + b^{2}}{a^{2} + b^{2} + 1} + \frac{b^{2} + c^{2}}{b^{2} + c^{2} + 1} + \frac{a^{2} + c^{2}}{c^{2} + a^{2} + 1}  $$

Comment: Solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h294652p1594873, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h293412p1586305, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h228995p1268669 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%20b%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%201%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%20c%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%201%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bc%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%20a%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%201%7D%20%5Cge%201%24&p=1)

Comment: This looks identical to your previous question (for which you accepted an answer).

Comment: @MartinR right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Schwartz inequality: $ (a^2+b^2+1)(1+1+c^2) \ge (a+b+c)^2$, which impies that $1\le \sum  \frac{1}{a^2+b^2+1}=\sum\frac{2+c^2}{(a^2+b^2+1)(1+1+c^2)}\le\sum\frac{c^2+2}{(a+b+c)^2}=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2+6}{(a+b+c)^2}\implies(a+b+c)^2\le a^2+b^2+c^2+6\implies a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)\le a^2+b^2+c^2+6 \implies ab+bc+ca\le3$